# How to create suggested input in actions on google while creating an google assistant app in dialogflow?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to put a prompt to allow user to choose while responding in google assistant app. I am creating this in dialog flow. How do I do this?

Comment: This seems a bit too broad for this site. This is likely covered in tutorials out there. What research have you done?

Comment: Okay gotcha! About research I am using google developer site tutorials to develop

Comment: Right, but you haven't _told_ us what you have tried, or showed what sort of code you have written to solve your problem. Check out [ask] and see if you can fit your query into the recommended format.

Comment: Sure thing will try that

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add "suggested input" items into your conversational experience as they show in the simulator or on a screen device, you are talking about "[Suggestion Chips](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip)". Here is what that looks like in the simulator:

[image]

Using Dialogflow you can go into an Intent, and go to Responses.  Go to the Google Assistant tab.  Add a response and choose the type "Suggestion Chips".  The input should match an intent.

Comment: Can you tell how to do it from code ("action-on-google" Client library) ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip (please upvote my answer if helpful)

Comment: @MarkScheel "The input is an intent name": I'm not sure this is true, when I click in a suggestion in the emulator, an intent that matches the text in the suggestion is trigged...

Comment: You are correct, I edited my response.  Thanks! I believe the GUI used to force you to use an Intent name when entering a suggestion chip.