# Adding input options (or card, tag ) in Dialog flow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to add suggested input options (or card or tag ) like in following picture in Dialogflow which i further will integrate with google Assistant..Can any one help me where to begin or start from .I have already seen Slot Filling,Contexts and follow-up Intents.Thanks in Advance..[image: ignore the first 2 lines]

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use a [Carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#carousel) rich response.

If you're using the actions-on-google library, your code might look something like this:

```
conv.ask(new Carousel({
  items: {
    // Add the first item to the carousel
    [SELECTION_KEY_ONE]: {
      synonyms: [
        'synonym of title 1',
        'synonym of title 2',
        'synonym of title 3',
      ],
      title: 'Title of First Carousel Item',
      description: 'This is a description of a carousel item.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_AOG,
        alt: 'Image alternate text',
      }),
    },
    // Add the second item to the carousel
    [SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_HOME]: {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Home Assistant',
        'Assistant on the Google Home',
    ],
      title: 'Google Home',
      description: 'Google Home is a voice-activated speaker powered by ' +
        'the Google Assistant.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_GOOGLE_HOME,
        alt: 'Google Home',
      }),
    },
    // Add third item to the carousel
    [SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_PIXEL]: {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Pixel XL',
        'Pixel',
        'Pixel XL',
      ],
      title: 'Google Pixel',
      description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_GOOGLE_PIXEL,
        alt: 'Google Pixel',
      }),
    },
  },
}));
```

If you're using the multivocal library, your configuration for the response might look something like

```
Local: {
  en: {
    Response: {
      "Action.options.get": {
        Template: {
          Text: "Here are the results"
          Option: {
            Type: "carousel",
            Items: [
              {
                Title: "First Option",
                Body: "First Body"
              },
              {
                Title: "Second Option",
                Body: "Second Body"
              },
              {
                Title: "Third Option",
                Body: "You guessed it, third body"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you are using JSON, your response should look something more like this

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Choose a item"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec",
          "carouselSelect": {
            "items": [
              {
                "optionInfo": {
                  "key": "first title"
                },
                "description": "first description",
                "image": {
                  "url": "https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png",
                  "accessibilityText": "first alt"
                },
                "title": "first title"
              },
              {
                "optionInfo": {
                  "key": "second"
                },
                "description": "second description",
                "image": {
                  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Nu3a6F80WfixUqf_ec_vgXy_c0-0r4VLJRXjVFF_X_CIilEu8B9fT35qyTEj_PEsKw",
                  "accessibilityText": "second alt"
                },
                "title": "second title"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(None of these examples include the suggestion chips, which you also indicated you wanted.)

When you handle the response, your Intent should handle the action `actions_intent_OPTION`.

Comment: i am getting >  ReferenceError: conv is not defined

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you're using and the error that you're getting. You didn't indicate what library you're using, so different libraries may handle it differently.

Comment: here is my code.Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192662/referenceerror-conv-is-not-defined

Comment: I've updated the response to include how to handle the response for the multivocal library and if you're using JSON directly. It sounds like you're using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your screenshot are suggested input chips, they are very easy to add.  Follow the instructions here: [How to create suggested input in actions on google while creating an google assistant app in dialogflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608897/how-to-create-suggested-input-in-actions-on-google-while-creating-an-google-assi/50674454#50674454)

Comment: i am getting >ReferenceError: conv is not defined

Comment: Please provide screenshots and the content of the debug tab in the simulator in your question.  This may be a new question, if so start a new one and link to it in the comments here.